# Function with Shiny Survey

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a function in R using Shiny Survey. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinysurveys)
library(shiny.semantic)

# Register a "check" input type
extendInputType("check", function() {
  shiny::checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = surveyID(),
    label = surveyLabel(),
    choices = surveyOptions()
  )
})

# Define question in the format of a shinysurvey
ice_cream_question <- data.frame(
  question = "Elija el software donde se trabajó este script.",
  option = c("Nfield", "Dimension", "Survey to Go","Question Pro"),
  input_type = "select",
  input_id = "favorite_ice_cream",
  dependence = NA,
  dependence_value = NA,
  required = TRUE
)

# Define shiny UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  surveyOutput(df = ice_cream_question,
               survey_title = "Procesamiento Mercaplan",
               theme = 'mercaplan'
  )
)

# Define shiny server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  survey_env <- new.env()  # Crear y inicializar el objeto survey_env

  # Observar cambios en la selección de tema y actualizar el tema en el entorno survey_env
  observe({
    survey_env$theme <- ifelse(input$theme == "mercaplan", "mercaplan", survey_env$theme)
  })

  renderSurvey()  # Renderizar la encuesta en la interfaz de usuario

  # Observar el evento de envío de la encuesta
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    response_data <- getSurveyData()  # Obtener los datos de la encuesta
    print(response_data)  # Imprimir los datos de la encuesta en la consola
  })
}

#' Aplicación Shiny para una encuesta interactiva sobre el software utilizado en un script.
#'
#' Esta aplicación utiliza el paquete "shinysurveys" para crear una encuesta interactiva en Shiny.
#' El usuario puede seleccionar el software utilizado en un script de una lista de opciones.
#'
#' @importFrom shiny shinyApp fluidPage
#' @importFrom shinysurveys extendInputType surveyOutput renderSurvey getSurveyData
#' @importFrom shiny.semantic surveyLabel surveyOptions
#' @return None
#' @examples pantalla
#' @export pantalla
#'
pantalla <- function() {
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

# Ejecutar la aplicación Shiny
return(pantalla())
```

Now I am trying to create the package with the following function in order to generate the .Rd file, but the following issue occurs.

```
devtools::load_all()
```

Loading procesamientomerca
Input Type "check" registered with {shinysurveys}. If the session restarts, you will need to re-register it.

To see all registered input extensions, please call `shinysurveys::listInputExtensions()`.
Warning messages:

1: object ‘surveyLabel’ is not exported by 'namespace:shiny.semantic'

2: object ‘surveyOptions’ is not exported by 'namespace:shiny.semantic'

3: Objects listed as exports, but not present in namespace:
• app

**I hope you can help me because this Shiny app needs to be composed of other functions.**